# Oracle Date Function Translation to BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

Need help translating this function to BigQuery from Oracle, the from_tz and timestamp formatting are giving me trouble:

```
trunc(from_tz(to_timestamp(trunc(llc.DATE) || ' ' || llc.HOUR, 'DD-MON-YY HH24MISS'), 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York') as the_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below approach. I used [timestamp functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) to create the query.

```
with sample_data as (
select date('2017-08-04') as date, time(10,00,00) as hour
)

select 
    format_timestamp( "%d-%b-%y %H%M%S", timestamp_trunc(timestamp(concat(date, ' ',hour),"UTC"),DAY,"America/New_York")) as out_format
from sample_data
```

NOTE: I created the sample data based from the query you have presented on your question. Let me know if I used incorrect data so I can edit the answer.

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. I removed the format_timestamp because I want to preserve the timestamp formatting with the migration. Thanks for your help.